# How can I use the Package LaTexStrings in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, latex, julia, jupyter

I am using Jupyter with the Julia Pro Kernel. And I want to just pass from a Julia Script to a Notebook.  (I am getting to jupyter via anaconda)

I use the command
`using LaTeXStrings` to charge that package in the jl file.  I use that command in order to put `\alpha` in the code and automatically appears the greek symbol α.

But when I am doing the same in Jupyter I just can't get the α.

I get this error as an output from that code chunk.

```
syntax: "\" is not a unary operator

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at In[18]:1
 [2] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1091
 [3] execute_code(::String, ::String) at C:\Users\jparedesm\.julia\packages\IJulia\rWZ9e\src\execute_request.jl:27
 [4] execute_request(::ZMQ.Socket, ::IJulia.Msg) at C:\Users\jparedesm\.julia\packages\IJulia\rWZ9e\src\execute_request.jl:86
 [5] #invokelatest#1 at .\essentials.jl:710 [inlined]
 [6] invokelatest at .\essentials.jl:709 [inlined]
 [7] eventloop(::ZMQ.Socket) at C:\Users\jparedesm\.julia\packages\IJulia\rWZ9e\src\eventloop.jl:8
 [8] (::IJulia.var"#15#18")() at .\task.jl:356
```

Does anyone know how can I get the greek alphabet in Jupyter? It'll be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to use the greek symbol alpha `α`. For that you don't need the package `LaTeXString`. You can just type `\alpha` and hit the `TAB` key. Then `\alpha` should automagically change to `α`.

`LaTeXStrings` is used to type LaTeX equations in string literals, like in `L"1 + \alpha^2"`